# How do change precision in coefficients in matrices

Tags: matrix, precision-and-accuracy

I alway have this kind of matrices...
[image]
obviously I would like to have 0s instead of 10^-15. I've tried with N[] function but doesn't work. Does anybody know how to proceed in this case?

Comment: Try [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) or [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html).

Comment: Better use `Threshold` with a desired tolerance as second argument. In contrast to `Chop`, it keeps packed arrays packed.